# SHT30 giving wrong humidity

Tags: sensors

I have an SHT30 sensor which is feeding to my Arduino via an RS485 connection. The readings are coming in as they should be for both temperature and humidity. The problem, however, is that the relative humidity I get from the SHT30 sensor is currently 45%, whereas the calculation of humidity from dry and wet bulb readings in the same conditions is 75%.

How can it be that my SHT30 reading differs by 30% from the actual calculated reading?

I confirm that all of the charts I have looked at place my relative humidity (given dry and wet bulb readings that I know are accurate) to be in the region of 75%. I know for certain, therefore, that it is my humidity sensor that is wrong.

Have you experienced this issue and, if so, how have you fixed it?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: There's really nothing here to go on. The performance of an SHT30 over time depends on several factors. I've never had one go too far out of its published specs except when damaged (too-high humidity for too long) but even then it wasn't *that* far off. You'll likely need to supply details beyond "it's wrong" though :)